# Demon maze boss not appearing. (HMH2)

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

I have just reached the final floor of the demon maze in half minute hero second coming. I opened all 5 gates to get into the last area but can find nothing. It is just an empty room.

I thought there was supposed to be a bonus boss there? Am I doing something wrong? How can I make the bonus boss appear?

Answer (score 1):

Having played further I have discovered the answer to this issue.

The boss will only appear if one has completed quest 73 in the story mode. (I do not wish to give unneeded spoilers but the bonus boss is a revamped version of the boss from this quest to explain the reasoning behind this.)

If you have not done this no hint is given, the boss room will simply be empty when the player arrives and you will have to leave and repeat the whole dungeon after completing this quest.